# Bar button item custom view not detecting UITapGesture

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am encountering some weird behavior, where a subview within a `UIBarButtonItem.customView` is not firing the `tapGesture`.

```
private var leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let b = UIBarButtonItem()
    return b
}()

private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    //... some adicional setup
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return iv
}()


func setupBBItem() {
    let holderView = UIView()
    holderView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    holderView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.frame = //... some frame
    //... more setups here
    
    holderView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    
    leftBarButtonItem.customView = holderView
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
    
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(someFunction))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

@objc private func someFunction() {
    print("tap gesture detected")
}
```

I have even tried to add the gesture to the `holderView` instead, but the result is the same, the function never fires.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
let holderView = UIView()
```

That is a zero size view. So its subview, the image view, can be seen but cannot be tapped, because any part of a view that is outside its superview is untouchable by the user.  You need to give the holder view some size, making it at least as big as the image view.  And in particular you must do this, both for the holder view and for the image view, using autolayout constraints internally. That is how a bar button item custom view gets its size.

Comment: Somehow it still doesn't work. I gave the `holderView` a CGRect frame, and gave one to the `imageView` as well, just in case and it still doesn't work.
I gave an image to the `imageView` as well, because it is only set afterwards, but still doesn't fire the `selector handler`.
I might be doing something wrong though.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It indeed solved the issue applying constraints... It's the first time I'm applying gestures to a subview of a bar button item custom view.
Thank you Sir.